# iOS: view height not set correctly in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, ios-4.2, viewdidload

I have a view controller loaded from a nib where I have a scroll view defined with a height of  346 pixels. However when I do:

```
int h = scrollView.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"%d",h);
```

in viewDidLoad I get 375.

I need the proper height in viewDidLoad (or another similar method) so that I can programatically set the contents of the scroll view depending on the height (don't want it to 'overflow' vertically, only horizontally, its paged).

The scroll view has every single autoresizing line turned on. (all bright red). Strangely, when the view loads I can see that the scroll view is (the proper) 346 pixels high not 375, so it must get changed to the proper value somewhere between viewDidLoad and displaying the view.

I'm at a dead end here and any way to get the proper size of a view would be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance, and if you need any more info please just comment.

edit: The way I solved it was by putting a timer for 0.1 seconds into viewDidLoad, and when that timer is called I did the work I needed to do. This is a bit of a hack though so any other advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling that code after `[super viewDidLoad]`?

Comment: benwong: No, I'd forgotten to call super, but I just added it at the beginning and nothing changed. I did manage to solve the problem with the hack I showed in my edit.

Comment: The height units that we see in code are ***not*** pixels. They are points. This is why we can write code and have it show up correctly on iPhone 4s and regular iPhones. Just a heads up for future reference :)

Comment: hehe, yeah I know, I was just being sloppy...

Comment: Here is a great answer for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6758424/864286

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct place to perform additional layout-type calculations is generally in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  [Docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews).  Also this from the section on "Handling View Rotations":

> The `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method is also called after the view is
>   resized and positioned by its parent. If a view controller is not
>   visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation methods
>   are never called. However, the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method is called
>   when the view becomes visible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, definitley looks like the right thing for people to do nowadays - that API didn't exist when I asked the question though :D

Comment: Correct; these methods were added in iOS5.  For pre-iOS5 you can do initial layout in viewDidAppear.  Or you can implement your own view subclass for your controller and override layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540935/176248).
You subview hasn't been placed and layouted within the superview. Get your view's size in `viewDidAppear:` for example.