# View is null in viewDidLoad

Tags: view, nib

I created `UITabBarController` with each tab contain `UINavigationController` and set rootviewcontroller in this `UINavigationController`, all of this is done in interface builder. In viewDidLoad I try to get frame size from view, but when I reference view it return null. Have anyone experienced this before.

All IBoutlet are properly  connected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` returning a nil view if the view is connected in your `.xib` could mean:

For programmatic initialisation (custom controllers):

- You forgot to call `initWithNibName:bundle:` on the view controller class altogether (you may have called `init` or something instead).
- You've overridden the `loadView` method in your view controller class, but it doesn't set the `view`.

For all controllers:

- An outlet connection hasn't been made correctly.
- You have accidentally released the view or view controller before showing it.
- The `nibName` parameter was not properly specified when initialising the view (the nib could not be found or one without a view was found.. though this should also throw an exception).
- There wasn't enough memory to allocate the `view` (the app would likely have been terminated by that point though).

I'd recommend you try doing frame size calculations in `viewWillAppear:` instead and see if the `view` is still `nil` at that point.

Comment: I didn't call any init because I'm using interface builder, and didn't override loadView.

I try calling view in viewDidLoad and the view is there. How come I can't refer it in viewDidLoad, I think I didn't miss all those list you point out for me.

Comment: Just try doing your calculations in `viewWillAppear` instead. And if that doesn't work, try `viewDidAppear`. If it isn't working by `viewDidAppear`, you're probably not accessing the `frame` properly (it must have a `frame` by the time it's drawn on screen).

Comment: Yes I can reference view in viewDidAppear, but I wan to set up view once and not every time the view did appear. Just wonder why view is null in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: You can test if the view is already set up, and only run your positioning code if it hasn't already been run. If it's just positioning, try adding a BOOL to your controller class, run the code block only when it's NO and set it to YES when the code runs. Otherwise, check whether your view is in the initial state rather than the set up state.

Comment: No offense, but this answer does not help and is incomplete. Like sarunw, I have initialization that must access subview objects, and must do so in `ViewDidLoad`, not whenever it appears. Also, what do you mean by "An outlet connection hasn't been made correctly"? And how would I check that "The nibName parameter was not[or was] properly specified"? The problem is that all storyboard-made views/subviews are null in `ViewDidLoad`, and they SHOULDN'T be. How do we fix this?

Comment: You have assumed this answer applies to the storyboard design method. It does not. This question was asked before storyboards existed.