# UITextField always nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm updating some [example code](https://github.com/adamski/ToDoLite-Swift/tree/Swift1.2) to the latest version of both Swift (from beta 4 to 1.2) and also the latest version of Couchbase Lite.

I'm having an issue with a UITextField always being nil. I've checked that its connected in the IB / xib file. I've disconnected and reconnected it to the `UITextField` object `addItemTextField`.

Its declared as

```
@IBOutlet weak var addItemTextField: UITextField!
```

and the relevant functions:

```
func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = detail.description
        }

        title = detail.title
        assert(addItemTextField != nil, "addItemTextField cannot be nil") // <- always hits this assertion
        addItemTextField.enabled = true
        addImageButton.enabled = true

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.title = "Share"

        assert(dataSource != nil, "detail.dataSource not connected")
        dataSource!.labelProperty = "title"
        dataSource!.query = detail.queryTasks().asLiveQuery()
    } else {
        title = nil
        addImageButton.enabled = false
        addItemTextField.enabled = false
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.configureView()
}
```

The ViewController its part of is instantiated with

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
```

(and of course i've checked the identifier is correctly set in the xib file)

Is there something I might have missed here?

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks @mikle94 I did a clean and build but still hit the same assertion

Comment: Is it nil in viewWillAppear? I've seen cases where a view is nill in DidLoad.. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266177/view-is-null-in-viewdidload

Comment: @Jay tried that, still nil... thanks anyway

Comment: If you have optimization level set for the compiler try setting it to none

Comment: @nikolayn Optimization is set to none for debug

Comment: Set breakpoints at the start of configureView and viewDidLoad and see which one is called first. It sounds like configureView gets called first. You'd need to fix the calling code to not call it so early.