# UIView size/position not working on iPad as on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview

I have a UIView of size width=320px height=40px which I want to display at the bottom looking like a tab-bar.

I use the following code to accomplish this and it works fine on iPhone. But when I try the iPad simulator, the view does not appear anywhere on the screen.

```
buttonsView.frame=CGRectMake(
                                0,
                                self.view.frame.size.height - buttonsView.frame.size.height,
                                self.view.frame.size.width,
                                buttonsView.frame.size.height );
```

This stretches the view to the width of the screen but keeps it's original height.

How can I make this show right on my iPad also?

**[UPDATE]**

This happens in my `viewDidLoad`.

I have this NSLog now:

```
NSLog(@"buttonsView Width: \t%g\t%g\tHeight:\t%g\t%g",self.view.frame.size.width, buttonsView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height, buttonsView.frame.size.height);
```

With output:
iPhone:

> buttonsView Width:     320 320 Height: 460 40

iPad:

> buttonsView Width:     768 768 Height: 1004    40

I also create another view like this for the top of the page which works fine:

```
dataView.frame=CGRectMake(
                             0,
                             0,
                             self.view.frame.size.width,
                             dataView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: When is this code being called? In `init`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because the `Auto Resizing` was set for the UIView's.

To fix, set the `Auto Resizing` to bind it to the top left corner. This way whenever you change the frame, it is relative to the top left pixel.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked (using breakpoints or `NSLog`) at the values you are putting into the `CGRectMake` call, just as a sort of "sanity check"?

---

Thanks for the info. My next thought is that between `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` something is being changed by the OS. Perhaps try moving the code to `viewWillAppear` so that you are guaranteed the frames you are working with will be the frames that will be displayed. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757018/why-am-i-having-to-manually-set-my-views-frame-in-viewdidload) explains it in a little bit more depth.

Comment: So you can use gdb to print out the values, as an alternative to NSLog

Comment: Have you removed my edit? Else I will post it as different answer...?

Comment: Removed your edit? Not sure I know what you are talking about.

Comment: Ah oke, some other moderator must have (It was awaiting approval)