# iPhone, screen gets drawn on very top, then it start to draw after menu bar on duel app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a strange bug.  I have a dual app.  When it first runs, y of zero is at the very top under the battery and signal strength bar.  When it goes to another view controller, it works fine, everything thing is shifted down so at y=0 is right under the menu bar.  When it returns to the first view controller, it is also drawn with the y being right after the menu bar.

This has never happen to me before, is it something to do with being a dual app ( my first dual app)
Ted

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when creating a universal app. See here: [Weird UIView coordinate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435814/weird-uiview-coordinate-issue)

The issue was the the Autosizing of views within the XIB. Once I went into IB and fixed that (either changed it or removed all autosizing options) things worked fine again.