# viewDidLoad and setting frame size in UIViewControllerContainment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

So I have a `UIViewController` inside a `UIViewController` and inside a `UIViewController` and I am trying to adjust its frame. However when I call `setFrame:`, it calls the `viewDidLoad` of that particular view controller I am trying to adjust the frame. However at that time the `frameSize` isn't the one that I set. In this `viewDidLoad` I am also calling a private method called `loadDataFromServer`, which pulls in data from memory first and then make a call to the server. Because it's loading data from memory, it does it really quick, basically before viewDidLoad is finished and therefore the frame size hasn't been adjusted yet. So I see the view with the wrong size/layout first and then it adjusts after getting data from the server, which at this point `viewDidLoad` is finished and the frame is adjusted well.

If I move the `loadDataFromServer` call to `viewDidAppear` then it all looks fine. The thing is that I am not sure when `viewDidAppear` is called. Is it called after `viewDidLoad` once? Or is it called after `viewWillAppear`? Any idea/work around for this?

```
    ContainerViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContainerViewController"];
    vc.delegate = self;

    UINavigationController *newsfeedNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

    [self addChildViewController:newsfeedNavController];
    newsfeedNavController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frameWidth, self.view.frameHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:newsfeedNavController.view];
    [newsfeedNavController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [newsfeedNavController release];
```

Comment: because I need some logic in it and it's just not a view.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I have a containerviewcontroller and a feedsviewcontroller, this feedsviewcontroller has some logic in it and is used as a subview of other viewcontrollers.

Comment: viewDidAppear is called after the main view of the particular view controller has been added to the view hierarchy of the parent view controller.

Comment: Use -viewWillLayoutSubviews on iOS 5 or -viewDidAppear: if you have to support earlier versions of iOS. Your view controller's view will have the correct bounds when either of these methods are called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I having to manually set my view's frame in viewDidLoad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757018/why-am-i-having-to-manually-set-my-views-frame-in-viewdidload)