# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit not working for UIScrollView subview UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

For hours I've been trying to figure out why the `UIScrollView` won't display the images from a `NSMutableArray`.

I realized the uiimageview objects are in the subview collection inside the UISCrollview but somehow the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit is ignored... How can I fit to scale then?

please, any tips?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    BookDalc* bookDalc = [[BookDalc alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray* books = [bookDalc FindByIconID:IconID];

    for(int i = 0;i<books.count;i++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrBook.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrBook.frame.size;

        UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        BookEntity *currentModel = [books objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *currentImage = [currentModel TheImage];

        subview.image = currentImage;
        [self.scrBook addSubview:subview];
    }
    self.scrBook.contentSize
    = CGSizeMake(self.scrBook.frame.size.width * books.count, self.scrBook.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: just a quick thought... have you tried self.scrBook.bounds.width instead of self.scrBook.frame.size.width, etc....?

Comment: that's hard to know from your code. do you have a sample project? did you try to just present 1 image on a view, to see if it's displayed properly?

Answer (score 1):

The frame of self.srcBook might not be set.

For more information read this answer.
[Why am I having to manually set my view's frame in viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757018/why-am-i-having-to-manually-set-my-views-frame-in-viewdidload)