# iOS 7 Custom TableView Is Under TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, tableview

Im trying port my app to `iOS7`, but my custom `TableViewController` is showing the last row (cell) under the `TabBar` :(

Im searching a lot for it, but i dont find any solution. Can anyone help me?

[My Custom Table View class](https://gist.github.com/prsolucoes/6821150)

The error is shown in the blow screenshot (only is showing a part of last product because im draging to up to show the hidden product under the tabbar):

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the answer to your question on another post, answered by dariaa, here:

[Tab Bar covers TableView cells in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325677/tab-bar-covers-tableview-cells-in-ios7)

It worked great for me.

Please no credit for me, because I'm not the original guy who solved it.

In your custom TableViewController, add these two lines under [super viewDidLoad]:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0., 0., CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue with my tab bar.

Answer (score 35):

I've got the same problem and solved it using storyboard.
At Tab Bar Controller, go to attribute inspector, Simulated Metrics, and set the Bottom Bar to Opaque Tab Bar. That's it!
See image bellow for description.
[image]

Saudações! (Greetings!)

Comment: Opaque is just a workaround : Don't use it, it's ugly.

Comment: After I have changed to Opaque Tab Bar, I change back to None then it still work.

Comment: You are a hero sir!

Answer (score 10):

My friends, I cannot tell you how badly I struggled from this. Not a single re-configuration of Story Board never helped me. The issue was exactly like in Original Post, I've managed to fix it using:

**for swift 3**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

**for objective-c**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = NO;
```

Comment: Unbelievable, but this was the answer for my problem with a view under the tabbar.

Answer (score 8):

2 lines in `viewDidLoad` and that's it !

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0.0f);
```

Comment: `UIRectEdgeAll` is set by default

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 7 viewController uses full height. There is a property introduced as

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

set it to no. then check, or set UIEdgeInset if is not set right after it.

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)
```

See here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

**Edit**: try also this

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: I put it (already tested if you see commented code). But nothing solved it :(

Answer (score 5):

The root cause of this problem is that `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is **effective only on the First** scroll view in your VC's view Hierarchy. It is not documented by Apple, but it is the only way the VC will detect the scroll view needing to be modified unless you're using a UITableViewController.

So in order to fix your issue without manually adjusting the insets, do this:

1. Make sure "Adjust Scroll View Insets" is checked.
2. Make sure that the tableView is the **first** subview in the view Hierarchy.
   (Move it upwards above all other elements)

Comment: Wow this made it possible to keep the translucent behaviour of the tabbar and still make the scrollview items to scroll above it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

UIViewController has two new properties to assist you : `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide`. They return the height of the parent view controller's controls you need to avoid. In this case, `bottomLayoutGuide` will return the offset of the tab bar.

Your custom view controller is probably overriding a method and not invoking `super`'s implementation where this would be done for you. I am guessing you are installing AutoLayout constraints or setting a view's frame manually to fill the view. You just need to include the value from `[bottomLayoutGuide length]` to your layout calculation. If you support rotation, you should update that value in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController` both have a transparency flag that can be set programmatically or in the storyboard.

The `UINavigationController` also has two flags that control if the content extends under the top or bottom bar. Again you can set them programmatically or in the storyboard. This will apply to all subviews.

Each `UIViewController` can set its own preference in code. The property is called `edgesForExtendedLayout` and you can set up all combinations.

Using those properties will allow AutoLayout and Springs'n'Struts to adjust the views the way you want them regardless of the device.

There are a lot more new properties in `UIViewController` that you will want to have a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])

 self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. One solution to it is to make the ToolBar **not** Translucent. Here's how to do it:

- First select the tool bar from the document viewer
  [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp60d.png)
- Then uncheck ***Translucent*** [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U26Rn.png)

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was masked using:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 112, 0);
}
```

But it doesn't solve, because on each iPhone and on each app tableview i have a different space on bottom.

So this is a poor solution.

I dont know a way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem now, changing my BaseTableViewController to inherit from UIViewController to UITableViewController.

But using a TableView inside a UIViewController is not solved :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is not a right answer, also for that reason I post this answer so you can tell me if this answer could be a possible solution.

In my case, I like the translucent effect, so I have added a footer in the table and I have modified the scrollIndicators.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.agendaItemsTable.frame.size.width, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
    self.agendaItemsTable.tableFooterView = footer;
    self.agendaItemsTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height, 0);

}
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the up-voted answers did not solve it. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21869659/1367622) to a similar question, [Tab Bar covers TableView cells in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325677/tab-bar-covers-tableview-cells-in-ios7).

I solved the issue by manually setting the table view's frame in the table view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method to the height of the screen - (status bar height + nav bar height + tab bar height).

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Adjust height of tableview (does not resize correctly in iOS 7)
    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height = [self heightForTableView];
    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
}

- (CGFloat)heightForTableView
{
    return CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) -
           (CGRectGetHeight([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]) +
            CGRectGetHeight(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame) +
            CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame));
}
```

If anyone finds a better solution to this problem, please share!

Comment: You're using viewWillAppear incorrectly for starters here. It's a common mistake. This should go in viewWillLoad. viewWillAppear fires every time the view appears! You don't want view setup code in that method firing every time your view appears. Only dynamic code that changes should go in viewWillAppear, such as data that's getting updated on the fly. You can call view logic if it's relevant to data updating, such as a view refresh. But view setup should never go in viewWillAppear.

Comment: cocoanut: In my experience, the frames of some views haven't always been set in viewDidLoad, but they are set in viewWillAppear, so computing geometries in viewDidLoad results in incorrect values if they need to be based on views in the nib.

Comment: @Jeff Agreed. I put this code in `viewWillAppear:` because there's no guarantee the frames will be set in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @cocoanut [This answer explains why you shouldn't put this code in viewDidLoad](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6758424/1367622).

Answer (score 0):

For those like xarly who **want the translucent effect**, and for an **Autolayout** solution (without setting frames), see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419986/1158074

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with collection view.  Changing the collection view frame and content inset below fixed it for me...

```
    guard let cv = collectionView,
        let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar else { return }

    // Resize collection view for tab bar
    let adjustedFrame = CGRect(origin: cv.frame.origin,
                               size: CGSize(width: cv.frame.width, height: cv.frame.height - tabBar.frame.height))
    cv.frame = adjustedFrame

    // Adjust content inset for tab bar
    let adjustedContentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, tabBar.frame.height, 0)
    cv.contentInset = adjustedContentInsets
    cv.scrollIndicatorInsets = adjustedContentInsets
```

Good luck!