# Tab Bar overlap view behind

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I can't seem to fix the issue about this where I adjusted the Tab Bar height to 60 from `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` but the overlay view doesn't seem to acknowledge the adjusted height and follow suit.

Other similar questions I found are not actually alike (see here: [iOS 7 Custom TableView Is Under TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19173630/1423345)) as their Tab Bar is translucent, and mine's not.

Here is what I implemented so far:

In my custom `UITabBarController`:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    var newTabBarFrame = tabBar.frame
    let newTabBarHeight: CGFloat = 60
    newTabBarFrame.size.height = newTabBarHeight
    newTabBarFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - newTabBarHeight
    tabBar.frame = newTabBarFrame
}
```

In one of my tab's `UIViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint( item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        ])
}
```

This is the current result:
[image: Here] You can see the overlay view is partially blocked. This happens on all other tab's overlay view controller

BTW, I already make sure the tableview's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `UITabBar` to do this. Just override `sizeThatFits(_:)` to use your custom height:

```
class TabBar: UITabBar {

    private let height:CGFloat = 60

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var bottomSafeAreaInsets: CGFloat = 0
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            bottomSafeAreaInsets = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        }
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: height + bottomSafeAreaInsets)
    }
}
```