# view.frame.width IS correct in viewDidLoad with storyboard, why?

Tags: ios

Ok, so this is somewhat of a weird question. I've been developing iOS-apps for quite a while and have always respected that `viewDidLoad` is the incorrect place for using the frame of the view.

However, in one app that I'm about to solve some bugs for, it seems that the frame is actually set correctly in `viewDidLoad`!

The storyboard is using "View as: iPhone 7", so I'm expecting to get 375px width for the frame in `viewDidLoad`. I'm using normal push segues.

However, the width is actually set correctly to the current devices screen width. I'm using a simulator.

What am I missing? Can we use the width for calculations in `viewDidLoad` nowadays?

Comment: try to check frame in ViewDidAppear .

Comment: @KKRocks The frame has actually changed origin and height (due to insets with navigation bar), but the width is still correct in viewDidLoad which is confusing me. I'm making it more clear in the question that it's the width that is concerning me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you still can't use `viewDidLoad` for anything size/position related.

The first method that will have the actual "proper" dimensions is the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Regarding the phenomenon you are experiencing.

You are probably talking about the "root view" from your view controller.

As the apple docs say (bolding is mine):

> **A view controller’s root view is always sized to fit its assigned
>   space**. For other views in your view hierarchy, use Interface Builder
>   to specify the Auto Layout constraints that govern how each view is
>   positioned and sized within its superview’s bounds. You can also
>   create constraints programmatically and add them to your views at
>   appropriate times. For more information about how to create
>   constraints, see Auto Layout Guide.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

This is why you are getting the correct width.

---

If you'd like to test, try adding a subview that fills the whole "root view" area. This one will probably just give you the dimensions that that are shown on the Interface Builder.

My test results:

**Interface Builder -> "View as iPhone 7"**

**Simulator iPhone 5s:**

```
Root View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
Sub View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
```

**Simulator iPhone 7:**

```
Root View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
Sub View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
```

**Simulator iPhone 7 Plus:**

```
Root View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0)
Sub View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
```

---

**Interface Builder -> "View as iPhone 4s"**

**Simulator iPhone 5s:**

```
Root View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
Sub View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)
```

**Simulator iPhone 7:**

```
Root View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
Sub View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)
```

**Simulator iPhone 7 Plus:**

```
Root View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0)
Sub View dimensions: (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)
```

As you can see, the root view dimensions will always correspond to the device you are using as stated in the documents. While any other views will have the dimensions you can see on the interface builder.

---

This question will also help you understand how the life cycle works:
[Why am I having to manually set my view's frame in viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757018/why-am-i-having-to-manually-set-my-views-frame-in-viewdidload)

Comment: Something tells me you have investigated this before the question was asked... :) Great, extensive answer, even with example! Kudos!

Comment: @Gero I've had my issues with a similar problem before, haha. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! It was indeed the root view :) Superb answer!