# UIDevice orientation returns portrait when device launches as landscape

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, uidevice

Heres a sample code that will print if the device is "portrait" or "landscape" when it first launches and also when it detects an orientation change.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getOrientation()
    }

    func getOrientation() {
        let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        if orientation == .landscapeLeft || orientation == .landscapeRight {
            print("landscape")
        }
        else {
            print("portrait")
        }
    }
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        getOrientation()
    }
}
```

If I launch the app with the phone portrait, it works fine. However, if I launch the app with the phone in landscape, it'll detect portrait at first. But if you rotate the device afterward it'll be correct. Is this a bug or am I using `UIDevice.current.orientation` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, your code is perfect, but the calling is not proper. `viewDidLoad` method doesn't guarantees the interface orientation or any UI related properties things it just says that `view` is loaded but in case if you want to guarantee to get the proper details then you should call it under `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: block)` (Main queue) which will give proper `orientation` or the other way is to call under `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but this has an disadvantage of calling multiple times depending on your views and subviews are resized.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.getOrientation()
}
```

Reference: [view.frame.width IS correct in viewDidLoad with storyboard, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500340/view-frame-width-is-correct-in-viewdidload-with-storyboard-why)

Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

The value of this property always returns 0 which is unknown, unless orientation notifications have been enabled by calling `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewWillTransition` method is only triggered when you rotate your device. You should try to call your `getOrientation` in `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

Update your test code

```
func getOrientation() {
     let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        if orientation == .landscapeLeft || orientation == .landscapeRight {
            print("landscape")
     }
     else if orientation == .unknown{
            print("unknown")
     }else if orientation == .portrait || orientation == .portraitUpsideDown{
            print("portrait")
     }
}
```

Comment: Code is fine! No need to change that!