# How to add a circleView progress to an UIView expanding to all UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have setup a `UIView` using constraints in a storyboard, and I want to add a circle progress to this view using `CAShapeLayer` with a `UIBezierPath`.

I have added this correctly, but the circle isn't expanded to all the view. i call this in my viewDidLoad function. My view has constraints to asjust height top-x view and width.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
borderLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
CGFloat lineWidth = 4;

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(lineWidth+lineWidth/2, lineWidth+lineWidth/2, self.myView.bounds.size.width/2, self.myView.bounds.size.height/2);
borderLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect].CGPath;
borderLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
borderLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
[borderLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[self.myView.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
}
```

The circle progress isn't resized to the `UIView`, and it is shown like this:

[image]

How can I draw this occupying the whole `UIView` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Your view's frame will not have been set yet in `viewDidLoad`. You need to move this code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or later in the view controller's lifecycle.

Related Question:

[Why am I having to manually set my view's frame in viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757018/why-am-i-having-to-manually-set-my-views-frame-in-viewdidload)

Apple Docs on view controller lifecycle: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1

2 - Change this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(lineWidth+lineWidth/2, lineWidth+lineWidth/2, self.myView.bounds.size.width/2, self.myView.bounds.size.height/2);
```

to this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(lineWidth/2, lineWidth/2, self.myView.bounds.size.width - lineWidth, self.myView.bounds.size.height - lineWidth);
```

Result (I used slightly different lineWidth and view size for my testing):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but replacing this line the circle appears in wrong position, is resized (like the double) and not centered

Comment: Where are you adding this borderLayer?

Comment: I'm adding this to my View, the gray UIView that you can see in picture. I'm using the last line: [self.myView.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];

Comment: I mean, where are you calling this code? Is it in `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, ...? Can you add the rest of your code?

Comment: ah sorry, I have updated my question. I call this into my viewdidload, could be this because my UIView has constrains into my autolayout storyboard?

Comment: Yes! thanks for your answer, this is the solution. First change my code to viewDidLayoutSubviews and then replace the line of CGRect declaration. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)