# UIViewController returns invalid frame?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, landscape

When I start my ViewController in `landscape` mode (After viewDidLoad is called), I print the frame it's giving me the frame size for portrait mode instead.

Is this a bug any suggestions?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
   // Result is (0, 0 , 768, 1024)
}
```

Comment: And what about viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you don't understand.

First, the system sends you `viewDidLoad` immediately after loading your nib.  It hasn't even added the view to the view hierarchy yet.  So it hasn't resized your view based on the device's rotation either.

Second, a view's frame is in its superview's coordinate space.  If this is your root view, its superview will be the `UIWindow` (once the system actually adds your view to the view hierarchy).  The `UIWindow` handles rotation by setting the transform of its subview.  This mean that the view's frame will not necessarily be what you expect.

Here's the view hierarchy in portrait orientation:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
(id) $1 = 0x09532dc0 <UIWindow: 0x9632900; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x96329f0>>
   | <UIView: 0x9634ee0; frame = (0 20; 768 1004); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9633b50>>
```

and here's the view hierarchy in landscape-left orientation:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
(id) $2 = 0x09635e70 <UIWindow: 0x9632900; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x96329f0>>
   | <UIView: 0x9634ee0; frame = (20 0; 748 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9633b50>>
```

Notice that in landscape orientation, the frame size is 748 x 1024, *not* 1024 x 748.

What you probably want to look at, if this is your root view, is the view's bounds:

```
(lldb) p (CGRect)[0x9634ee0 bounds]
(CGRect) $3 = {
  (CGPoint) origin = {
    (CGFloat) x = 0
    (CGFloat) y = 0
  }
  (CGSize) size = {
    (CGFloat) width = 1024
    (CGFloat) height = 748
  }
}
```

Presumably you want to know when the view's transform, frame, and bounds get updated.  If the interface is in a landscape orientation when your view controller loads its view, you will receive messages in this order:

```
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} viewDidLoad
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} viewWillAppear:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} viewWillLayoutSubviews
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} layoutSubviews
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} viewDidLayoutSubviews
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} viewDidAppear:
```

You can see that your view's bounds change *after* you receive `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and *before* you receive `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

The `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` methods are new to iOS 5.0.

The `layoutSubviews` message is sent to the view, not the view controller, so you will need to create a custom `UIView` subclass if you want to use it.

Comment: the key thing for me was using bounds instead of frame. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Rob, hopefully you see this -- how did you get that dump of the order of the methods invoked when the controller loads its view?

Comment: I put an `NSLog` in each method.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. The simple chronological list of methods is amazingly useful, and something that should be prominent in Apple's documentation. Even better would be a state diagram for the various transitions that can then occur, with the method call ordering on the edges.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a clean solution.

I was experiencing the same issue and I insist on using `frame` throughout my app. I do not want to make an exception for the root view controller. I noticed that the root view controller's `frame` was displaying portrait dimensions, *but all subviews had correct landscape dimensions*.

Since it is only the root view controller that behaves differently, we can set a standard, blank view controller as the root view controller and add our custom view controller to that. (Code below.)

You can then use `frame` as you intend to, in your custom view controller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.window.rootViewController addChildViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.viewController.view];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution (**Swift 4**):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Basically this forces the view controller to correctly layout it's view and from there you can get the correct frames for all your subviews. This particularly helps when doing transition animations and your view controllers are using autolayout and interface builder.

From what I've noticed it looks like the initial frames are set to whatever your interface builder's default size class is set to. I normally edit using the iPhone XS size class so in `viewDidLoad` it seems that the view's width is always 375 regardless whether you are using an iPhone XR or not. This corrects itself before `viewWillAppear` though.

The above code will correct this issue and allow you to get the correct frames for your view / subviews before the view controller is rendered to the screen.