# On an iOS single view app, when is the earliest time that self.view.bounds is set correctly?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add a `UITableView` object that covers up the whole screen, by

```
  UITableView *tabelView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [self.view addSubview:tabelView];
```

but I realized that even if a physical iPad 2 is rotated to Landscape mode, `self.view.bounds` is `{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}}` in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.  Only in `viewDidAppear` is it finally `{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}}`

What is the earliest time that `self.view.bounds` is set correctly to `{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}}`?  If `viewDidAppear` is the one, then I have to create the `UITableView` there, and if the "Launch image" is a static Landscape blank table, then the screen will flash a white screen when `viewDidAppear` is called, and then the table is added and seen, so a flash of white screen is seen.

So when is the earliest time that `self.view.bounds` is set correctly to `{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}}`?  It seems like it needs to be slightly before `viewDidAppear`, so that the blank table is drawn (with the grey lines), and show it and seamlessly get displayed to cover up the Launch image.  If the table is created in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` using `self.view.bounds`, then the table ends up being 768 points wide and is meant for the Portrait mode.

**Update: I just tried to add the Launch image and for some reason, even if the `UITableView` is added in `viewDidAppear`, the "flash of white screen" didn't happen... I don't know why, but previously if I use `CALayer` and bitmap to show content, and didn't use any view or `drawRect`, then the flash occurred...  by the way, the earliest one I found was `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, and then later in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, both of which happened before `viewDidAppear`, and both showed `self.view.bounds` as `{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}}`**

**Update 2: What if the view is complicated and time consuming to make?  To test, I added a `usleep(100000);` in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` to sleep 0.1 second for each cell, and the "flash" did occur... but cell and table supposedly should be light weight and fast to make, but what if there are other type of views that are more time consuming to make?  If I move `UITableView` creation to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, then it is still slow to show something, but at least there is no "flash".  However, later on when I rotate the device, it actually call `viewWillLayoutSubviews` again and add another table to the main view (with correct screen size), so `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will need to remove any old table view first, if any, or just resize the old one and not add a new one.**

Comment: Whilst the self.view.bounds updates later on, if you grab the interface orientation using [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation you can decide how to size your table before waiting for the bounds to be set.

Comment: @Luke if this work, this may be a little bit of a hack because what if a future device of iOS comes out, and it is not the iPhone or iPad resolution and we need to count on `self.view.bounds`?

Comment: Apple tend to be kind with these things, but whilst I understand what you're saying, you could do it this way anyway (as you want to draw the table before the view appears) and then compare the frame you generated with the final self.view.bounds and then adjust if necessary.

Comment: @Luke please see update in the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIViewController returns invalid frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539676/uiviewcontroller-returns-invalid-frame)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to avoid the flash is to create the table view in `viewDidLoad` and set the table view's autoresizing mask properly, so that the system automatically makes the table view fill its superview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

Otherwise, the earliest time that you can see the final view bounds are in the view controller's `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method.  You would add your table view once in `viewDidLoad`, and then adjust its frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or a method called after that.  See my answer to [UIViewController returns invalid frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539676/uiviewcontroller-returns-invalid-frame) for more details.

Comment: actually, it does work -- there is no flash even if I add a `sleep(1)` in the cell data source provider, so even though the table is very slow to come out (say, 5 or 10 seconds), there is no flash, and it is an interesting concept: we first set the view to an "incorrect" size first, and let the "resize" handle it before showing it on screen

Comment: is there a `viewWillResizeSubviews` also? I googled and searched in the link in your answer and don't see a resize message like that?

Comment: There is no `viewWillResizeSubviews` message.  A view only resizes its subviews when it performs autolayout, and you receive `viewWillLayoutSubviews` immediately after that.

Comment: because you mentioned `viewWillResizeSubviews` in your answer... where does it belong to?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve a similar problem - I wanted to load some UI elements programmatically based on the size of a `UIView` added in Interface Builder.

Inside `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`, the `UIView` still hadn't had its frame/bounds set. Placing my code inside `viewDidAppear` worked, however it meant that the UI would "flash" with an update rather than appearing already loaded when the `UIViewController` was pushed onto the navigation stack.

I found that overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` solved the problem - at that point, the view had its bounds and frame set - I could add in my own subviews relative to its size, all before `viewDidAppear`.

The end result is that the UI loaded properly before it appeared, and hence didn't "flash" in for the user.