# iOS bounds change after rotating to landscape, then back to portrait

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

When my application launches, an NSLog of my view's bounds shows the following:

```
NSLog(@"My view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
My view frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 548}}
```

I then rotate the simulator and get the following:

```
NSLog(@"My view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
My view frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 548}}
```

Then when I rotate the simulator back to portait, I get this:

```
NSLog(@"My view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
My view frame: {{0, 0}, {568, 300}}
```

The two methods I'm using to adjust elements are these, they aren't done yet, as I'm currently in the middle of fixing them for the new iphone.

```
-(void) resizeForLandscape
{
    newsLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:50];
    weatherLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:51];
    sportsLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:52];
    entertainmentLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:53];
    videosLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:54];
    moreLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:55];

    NSLog(@"resizeForLandscape called");
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 31, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 75);    
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width -30, image.size.height -15);
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(230, 100, 80, 21);
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height + 15, 30);

    NSLog(@"My view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
    NSLog(@"my status bar height is %f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"my status bar width is %f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width);


    newsLabel.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.height - 346) / 2 + 12, self.view.bounds.size.width - 38, 43, 21);
    weatherLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 64, self.view.bounds.size.width - 38, 42, 21);
    sportsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 126, self.view.bounds.size.width - 38, 42, 21);
    entertainmentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 185, self.view.bounds.size.width - 38, 66, 21);
    videosLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 269, self.view.bounds.size.width - 38, 42, 21);
    moreLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 325, self.view.bounds.size.width - 38, 42, 21);

    spacer1.width = (self.view.bounds.size.height - 346) / 2;
    spacer2.width = 40;
    spacer3.width = 28;
    spacer4.width = 42;
    spacer5.width = 35;
    spacer6.width = 24;
}

-(void) resizeForPortrait
{
    newsLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:50];
    weatherLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:51];
    sportsLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:52];
    entertainmentLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:53];
    videosLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:54];
    moreLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:55];

    NSLog(@"resizeForPortrait called");

    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height -88);
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(145, 152, 80, 21);
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 315, 40);

    NSLog(@"My view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));

    NSLog(@"my status bar height is %f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"my status bar width is %f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width);


    float myWidth = MIN(self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width);
    float myHeight = MAX(self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width);

    newsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x, myHeight - 18, 43, 21);
    weatherLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 43, myHeight - 18, 42, 21);
    sportsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 97, myHeight - 18, 42, 21);
    entertainmentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 138, myHeight - 18, 66, 21);
    videosLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 213, myHeight - 18, 42, 21);
    moreLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newsLabel.frame.origin.x + 258, myHeight - 18, 42, 21);


    spacer1.width = (myWidth - 346) / 2;
    spacer2.width = 20;
    spacer3.width = 18;
    spacer4.width = 25;
    spacer5.width = 28;
    spacer6.width = 14;
}
```

Called by:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self resizeForLandscape];
    } else {
        [self resizeForPortrait];
    }
}

- (void) getOrientationandResize
{    
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        [self resizeForLandscape];
    } else {
        [self resizeForPortrait];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self getOrientationandResize];
}
```

My head is about to explode. Not only are the views reversed, but 20 pixels have been robbed from the width and given to the height. Can anyone explain this to me and how I could/should code the elements in my view to account for it?

My storyboard is as follows:

[image]

My initial view:
[image]

After first rotation (still good)
[image]

Rotating back to portrait (all screwed up because of the bounds values)
[image]

Comment: I would guess that your bounds are being set before the windows bounds are. As far as the 20px that's going to be the Status Bar at the top.

Comment: What methods are being called when you rotate from the delegate? Are you using IB?

Comment: I figured the 20px was the status bar, but why does it only show up after the two rotations? Shouldn't it be there from the beginning? Also, as an extra bit of weirdness, when I print out the status bar height after I rotate back to portait ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height), it says this: my status bar height is 568.000000.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the width 20px?

Comment: I just tested it, when you rotate it doesn't change the bounds of the statusbar, just rotates them

Comment: Is this an autorotating view?

Comment: WHen my app starts, the statusbar width is 320, height is 20. WHen I rotate to landscape, it stays the same, when I rotate back to portait, it then becomes height: 568.000000 width: 20.000000.

Comment: Shizam, yes, I believe so. i.e. I just call willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, check the orientation then adjust some elements.

Comment: Are you using InterfaceBuilder to handle struts/springs?

Comment: Okay I added more code and screenshots to hopefully paint a more complete picture.

Comment: How does `resizeForLandscape` get called?  Show us the method that calls it.

Comment: It's called by willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and viewDidAppear, I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should pretty much never do layout in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.  When the system sends you `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, **it has not updated your view's frame to its new size**.  So by consulting `self.view.frame`, you're using the frame for the current (old) orientation, **not** the frame for the new (not-yet-rotated-to) orientation.

You should also not do layout in `viewDidAppear:`, because by the time you receive `viewDidAppear:`, your view is already on the screen.  You need to do layout **before** your view is on the screen.

You need to do your layout in an appropriate method.  The best place to do layout is in the `layoutSubviews` method of a custom `UIView` subclass.  Putting it there keeps your view logic separate from your controller logic.

The next-best place to do your layout is in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your view controller.

If you put your layout code in `layoutSubviews`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, the system will **automatically** call that method before your view appears on-screen, and inside the animation block of an autorotation.  In both cases, it will update your view's frame for the correct orientation before sending you the message.

If you need to do something like hide a view before the autorotation animation starts, and show it again after, you can do that in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

If you want to perform special animations **only** during an autorotation, and not during initial view layout, you can do that in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, which is called inside the animation block of an autorotation.

You may find this answer helpful: [UIViewController returns invalid frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539676/uiviewcontroller-returns-invalid-frame/9540935#9540935)

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try and get back to you!

Comment: Yeah, viewDidLayoutSubviews was the answer to my woes.

Comment: Excellent info to guide in the correct way of doing things.  (+1)