# xCode Tableview set bounds

Tags: xcode, tableview, setbounds

Trying to set the bounds of my table view to be smaller than my screen. I am setting it in my viewDidLoad method but nothing happens when I run. Not sure why it's not working. Am I calling it in the right place??

```
 //OptionsViewController.m

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(1,1,29,80);
 }

 //  OptionsViewController.h
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface OptionsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
 {
     NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex;
 }

 @property (weak, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

 @end
```

Comment: are you also taking table view in story board?? if so then delete the tableview from storyboard and give it the bounds programatically like you are doing in viewDidLoad. I am just asking because you have taken IBOutlet of tableView, and if you are creating tableView dynamically you do not need to use IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame in viewDidAppear method . It works. You might want to look at the following question and answer for a good explanation :

[Unable to set frame correctly before viewDidAppear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079172/unable-to-set-frame-correctly-before-viewdidappear)

TL;DR - The UI elements are not drawn to screen yet during viewDidLoad .