# How do I make two equally sized imageviews cover the whole screen

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I implemented a viewcontroller similar to the one in this question:
 [iOS two views cover exactly half of parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769847/ios-two-views-cover-exactly-half-of-parent-view)

I get the desired result. The problem is that when I add a UIImageView into those two containers, the result get resized and ruins the symmetry. How do I prevent Imageviews from changing the size of their containers? I need to use AspectFill for these images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the containers' sizes are changed. You just need to set their `clipsToBounds` property to true to avoid overflow.

If you use Reveal you should see the containers' sizes are not changed even if pictures inside them are bigger than themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure I understand what you mean about adding UIImageView into those controllers causing the views to resize, so forgive me if I'm getting this all wrong...

It sounds as though you've created two views of equal height that, together, consume the entire vertical space of the screen. After having done that, you want to add one or more UIImageView's to each of the original two views. Unfortunately, when you add the UIImageView, the enclosing view is resized.

Assuming I have that correct...

Are you doing this with Interface Builder either in an XIB or Storyboard file?  If so, you ought to be able to achieve this with the proper set of constraints.

In the following image, I've laid out what I describe above.

[image: Upper, Lower, and ImageView]

As you can see, I have a red view on the top half of the window and a green view on the bottom half. The red view contains a UIImageView that is 75% of the width and height of red view, with its origin at (20, 20) within the red view.

The scene is configured as shown below:

[image: View Scene]

The constraints on "Upper View" are:

[image]

You can see from this that Upper View is flush with the left, right, and top of its superview, and that its space to Bottom View is 0. You'll have to trust me that Bottom View is set up the same way.

The height of the Upper and Lower views is "Proportional" as shown in this constraint:

[image]

To achieve this "Proportional" setting, you first make the height of Upper View equal to the height of the superview, and then edit the constraint, changing "Multiplier" from "1" to "0.5."

The height (and width) of the Image View is proportional to that of the Upper view, as shown here:

[image]

If you set it up this way, you ought to be able to accomplish what (I think) you are looking to accomplish.

If my original assumption of what you are trying to achieve is incorrect, please post images of what you've got and how it's not working.