# Why does adding subview in viewDidLoad doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I was trying to add UIToolBar into a UIWebView but whenever I insert this code inside viewDidLoad UIToolBar doesn't show up, however when this is done in viewWillAppear, it works. Can someone please explain it to me.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.forwardButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Forward"          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(forward)];
self.backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back)];
NSArray *buttonsArray = @[self.backButton,self.forwardButton];
CGRect toolBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:toolBarFrame];
[self.toolbar setItems:buttonsArray animated:YES];
[self.toolbar sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];
}
```

Comment: seems like storyboard to me but anyways... to clear things up, check similar questions: [Unable to set frame correctly before viewDidAppear](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13079172/2857130) or [UIViewController returns invalid frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9539676/2857130)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add subview in `viewDidLoad`, but set its `frame` in `viewWillAppear`. `self.view.frame` is being set just before `viewWillAppear` is called by UIKit. The value you get in `viewDidLoad` is the one was set in nib and is often different from the actual `frame`.

Don't forget to set `autoresizingMask` or use auto layout.

Comment: is bounds set before the frame then?

Comment: UIKit sets correct dimensions just prior to `viewWillAppear:` meaning that `frame`, `bounds` and `center` will be set. All these properties are backed by the same attributes of corresponding `CALayer` so, unless `transform` is set you should expect similar behavior from both `frame` and `bounds` in terms of "correctness". Hope it makes sense.