# How to get the real frame after autoresized an UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, autoresize

I have an UIView that is set to autoresize depending the partent view, The problem is that the frame returns the original size even when it is autoresized.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
       NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));}
```

it is returns the original size!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use one of the viewController lifecycle function to get the real size of the subviews.

One of them will work:

- viewDidLayoutSubviews
- viewDidAppear

For more details check the answer of this question:
[Unable to set frame correctly before viewDidAppear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079172/unable-to-set-frame-correctly-before-viewdidappear)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is also worked when I use layoutSubviews