# How to get CAShapeLayer() circle to resize based on the size class

Tags: ios, swift, geometry, cashapelayer, size-classes

I'm trying to create a circle using CGPoint and CGFloat. But I want the circle to be different in siz based on which device is used. I changed all my Size classes to reflect the sizes I want and I was hoping, it would recognise that but it doesn't.

WhiteBar is a UIView within my main view that I created using SB and to test that my view is changed in the size class, I set a background color and saw its set as I want it

my print line shows me the smallest width and height

```
@IBOutlet var WhiteBar: UIView!
var WhiteCircle = CAShapeLayer()
WhiteCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
WhiteCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
WhiteCircle.lineWidth = 15
WhiteCircle.strokeStart = 0
WhiteCircle.strokeEnd = 1

let WhiteCenterPoint = CGPoint (x: WhiteBar.bounds.width / 2, y: WhiteBar.bounds.height / 2)
let WhiteCircleRadius : CGFloat = (WhiteBar.bounds.height / 2 -  WhiteCircle.lineWidth / 2)

println(WhiteBar.bounds.width) // outputs the smallest size of all my size classes
println(WhiteBar.bounds.height) // outputs the smallest size of all my size classes

var WhiteCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: WhiteCenterPoint, radius: WhiteCircleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true)

WhiteCircle.path = WhiteCirclePath.CGPath

WhiteBar.layoutIfNeeded()

WhiteBar.layer.addSublayer(WhiteCircle)
```

**EDIT: It seems the size is set based on the w: Any h: Any size class.**

Thanks in advance,
Ace

Comment: Where is this code you have posted placed?

Comment: In func TrackProgress() which I call in my func viewDidLoad()

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrollview size with Autolayout: frame is 600x480 in compact/Any size class, bigger than iphone5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703078/scrollview-size-with-autolayout-frame-is-600x480-in-compact-any-size-class-big)

Comment: possibly!!! Anyways I got my CAShapeLayer to work and this can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size classes (or any auto layout changes, for that matter) are not applied until after viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews. You will need to move this code into one of those. You are seeing the bounds of the view as it is loaded out of the Interface Builder document (xib or storyboard). You should never be checking frames or bounds until after those lifecycle events.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704658/72319

Comment: Haha I went through your profile and came across that post already :) But My fun TrackProgress is called within my viewDidLoad so its that the same?

Comment: Yes, viewDidLoad happens first of the view lifecycle methods.

Comment: No, any code checking the status of views post auto layout must happen after viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews are called (that can be inside of them).

Comment: "that can be inside of them" within is inside of them. So it CAN or CAN NOT be inside viewDidLoad? if so, where can I put it, if I want it to be available when the view loads

Comment: Look at this diagram: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-xamarin-studio/9781783550814/ch06s02.html constraints aren't applied until viewDidAppear/viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Ok so I tried putting it in the override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(false)
        
        TrackProgress()
        
    } And the result is the same. It only considers the w: any h: any size class which has no constraints on that subview since it changes in each size class

Comment: I told you that it only happened after viewDidAppear viewWillAppear is clearly before that.

Comment: How? The arrows are point down. Init -> loadView -> viewDidLoad -> viewWillAppear

Comment: Nothing above viewDidAppear will contain the proper frames.