# Set UIView's size same as the entire window's size

Tags: ios, objective-c

**EDIT:**

The UIWebView is first initialized in `FirstViewController` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview: self.webView];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

The reference to this `UIWebView` is passed on to the `SecondViewController`, and I add it as a subview like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
}
```

This attaches a UIWebView into a View Controller's view. If I call this function inside `viewDidAppear`, I get a UIWebView that fits the whole screen. However, if I call it inside `viewWillAppear`, UIWebView only takes half the whole screen's size. I tried comparing `viewController.view`'s sizes for `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` but they seemed to be the same.

According to this very similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079172/unable-to-set-frame-correctly-before-viewdidappear) it's appropriate to resize subviews in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. So I tried the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

but it still looks like this:

[image]

Comment: So why don't you put in `viewDidAppear `?

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: The user sees a blank screen for a split second if I do that.

Comment: @Bannings Yes. The View Controllers in the storyboard are basically empty  and I am adding the UIView (UIWebView) programmatically.

Comment: @MaximusS When do you set the frame of the `UIWebView`?

Comment: Did you try to print `self.view.bounds` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the `UIWebView` inside `viewDidLoad` like so:

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.webView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

or adjusting its size inside `didLayoutSubviews` as @anhtu said:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds;` doesn't work. Could you look at the screenshot?

Comment: What's type of the `self.view`?

Comment: `UIView*`. `self` refers to the ViewController that contains everything.

Comment: Try this `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: It's just a guess that you wrapping the `viewController` in `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController`, so the `webView`'s contentInsets will to be adjusted.

Comment: `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` works a bit differently in iOS 8. In 7, it only applied if the controller's view property was a scrollView. In 8, it seems to apply to scroll views that are subviews of the controllers' view.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't resize UIView in `viewWillAppear`. It will be resize again same as in Interface Builder. If you don't want to put in `viewDidAppear`, you can try put in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Seems to be the same.

viewWillAppear: 375.000000, 667.000000
viewDidAppear: 375.000000, 667.000000
NSLog(@"viewDidAppear: %f, %f", self.webView.bounds.size.width, self.webView.bounds.size.height);

Comment: How about in `viewDidLayoutSubviews ` ?

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called three times for some reason, but all the times it's the same size as well. `375.000000, 667.000000`

Comment: Does it work in `viewDidAppear ` ? Or not in `viewDidAppear ` also.

Comment: `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` did the trick. Thank you so much for helping me out too!

Answer (score 0):

try these..

```
UIView *viewAll=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:viewAll];
```

i hope it helps..