# Wrong frame values for UIButton

Tags: uibutton, frame, cgrect

I have a scene with a UIButton placed on it which has these parameters:
origin=(x=131, y=136) size=(width=**760**, height=570)

In **viewDidLoad** I put these coordinates into a CGRect variable:

```
CGRect myRect  = _mainImage.frame;
```

When checking myRect in Landscape orientation with NSLog I get this:
origin=(x=131, y=136) size=(width=**504**, height=570)

But the width value **504** is the value for Portrait orientation.
When using the same thing in Portrait orientation I´m getting the same values.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIViewController returns invalid frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539676/uiviewcontroller-returns-invalid-frame)

Comment: No, no duplicates, I also tried the same thing with UIImageView and different Name with the same result.