# landscape mode don't work properly in spritekit game

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

i started a platformer game in spriteKit and i have a little problem with landscape mode.
When i make a jump with my hero, I use the

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

and while the hero it's in the air and collides with a wall or any object and miss his speed, then i use the

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];

CGPoint posicionHero = [self.world childNodeWithName:@"hero"].position;
SKSpriteNode *touchHero = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:posicionhero];

//pragma mark -hero movement in the air

if ((touchedNode != touchHero)
    &&
    (positionInScene.x > [self.world childNodeWithName:@"hero"].position.x))
{
    [[self.world childNodeWithName:@"hero"].physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(5, 0)];
}
if ((touchedNode != touchHero)
    &&
    (positionInScene.x < [self.world childNodeWithName:@"hero"].position.x))
{
    [[self.world childNodeWithName:@"hero"].physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(-5, 0)];
}

}
```

to keep that speed. 
I've been testing in portrait mode and everything were ok, but my game it's in landscape mode, so finally I have blocked the game to landscape mode, and now I'm testing it in landscape mode and I'm having troubles, because when I move my finger forward in a jump, nothing happens. Instead of this I have to move my finger upward, to get that movement. I'm sure i'm missing some basic configuration for my landscape mode. Any help will be apreciated

Comment: Did you try changing X coordinates by Y coordinates? Also remember that locationInNode uses a coordinate system where the origin is in the bottom left corner, instead of the top left corner as in UIViews.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually a common problem in SpriteKit games. This occurs because `viewDidLoad` actually runs before the app checks for device orientation. You can fix it by replacing `viewDidLoad` with `viewWillLayoutSubviews` which will run after device orientation detection. For example, you could replace the default SpriteKit `viewDidLoad` with this:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

For more information, checkout these sources:
[UIViewController returns invalid frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539676/uiviewcontroller-returns-invalid-frame)
http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners