# Stop SKSpriteNode from leaving view (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Hello i want to prevent a SKSpriteNode from leaving the screen or to make the Node bounce back when it hits the border of the screen. And is it also possible to call a function when its hits the border?

If found this question [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261503/skspritenode-ball-not-colliding-with-border)

Where he uses this code:

```
let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
self.physicsBody = borderBody
borderBody.friction = 0.0
borderBody.restitution = 1.0
```

But for some reason it only block my Node (which is dynamic) from moving out of the the top and bottem, but It's able to move out of the side.

(Keep in mind that im new to SpriteKit and Swift)

EDIT: i found this code:

```
extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        switch (contactMask) {
        case BodyType.pipe.toRaw() |  BodyType.bomb.toRaw():
            println("Contact with a bomb")
            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.pipe.toRaw() {
                explode(pipe: contact.bodyA.node as SKSpriteNode)
            } else {
                explode(pipe: contact.bodyB.node as SKSpriteNode)
            }
        case BodyType.pipe.toRaw() |  BodyType.bird.toRaw():
            println("Contact with a pipe")
            bird.pushDown()
        case BodyType.ground.toRaw() | BodyType.bird.toRaw():
            println("Contact with ground")
            for actor in actors {
                actor.stop()
            }

            let shakeAction = SKAction.shake(0.1, amplitudeX: 20)
            screenNode.runAction(shakeAction)
        default:
            return
        }

    }
```

I read it was something like setting categories? Is this code anygood?

Comment: you have to look into the collision detection. See Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

Comment: Your scene is larger than your view. Try changing the scaleMode from .AspectFill to .ResizeFill in GameViewController.swift.

Comment: @0x141E, i tried your suggestions, it makes the left of the screen bounce back but, on the right side it doesnt work..?

Comment: Change your physics body declaration to use the view's frame instead of the scene's frame: let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: view.frame)

Comment: @0x141E, due to the universal viewcontrollers that doesnt work

Comment: Why does that matter? It works with iPad and iPhone 6/6+ simulators.

Answer (score 3):

Set the physics body to the size of the screen

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

Comment: Hey, I am trying to make a side scrolling game, is there anyway to make this physics body move and follow the player when he moves?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

- You've got to set up an SKNode with physics body of type rect and give it the size of self.size. This will create a physics body for the screen borders.
- Then you must set up a categorybitmask on the physics body of above SKNode. This is a way we can identify our physics body.
- And the then you've got to give the above SKNode a collisionbitmask equal to the categorybitmask of the Node you don't want leaving the screen. This will make the node crash into the border and bounce back in.
- Finally if set the contacttestbitmask of either to the categorybitmask of the other. The apple function "didBeginContact" will be run, and in there you could do something about it.

Hope that helps!