# SpriteKit coordinate system messed up

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift

In portrait mode, i created a `SKShapeNode` at the position of `0,0`. Yet it seems that it does not appear in the screen at all.

This is the code i am using now

```
let test = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
test.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
self.addChild(test)
```

The background colour white, so the shape node will definitely appear if it was on the screen

Yet 0 node appears in the screen? 
`children.count` returns 1

And this is how i display the scene

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews () {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

The `SKShapeNode` is drawn, but it is outside the screen?

EDIT 1: I change the scale mode to `.AspectFit`, and this is what happened
[image]
Is the game forcefully running in landscape although the game is suppose to run in portrait?

Comment: check that scene.size is correct and scale mode is aspect fit or resize fill. The debug draw node count only counts nodes visible on screen, if you want to count nodes in the scene graph log children.count

Comment: the standard scale mode in Xcode for me is .AspectFill, children.count returns 1

Comment: looks like the scene was designed for landscape while app is in portrait

Comment: How do i fix it then?

Answer (score 3):

Base on @fuzzygoat answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170460/1879382.

Simply open `GameScene.sks`, then change the value of x and y to the appropriate value needed.
For me, I used 320 x 568 since i run the game on iPhone 5S

Comment: should be 320x568 unless you had a reason to make the scene one point (2 pixels) wider

Comment: My bad, though @fuzzygoat also said it 320x569, i will change it