# SKShapeNode position line up with ground

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I am simply trying to draw a rectangle and placing it in the bottom left hand side of the screen

```
    var rectW:CGFloat  = CGFloat(200.0)
    var rectH:CGFloat = ceil(self.frame.height * 0.15)

    var rect = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: rectW, height: rectH));

    let posX:CGFloat = 0.0 + (rect.frame.width / 2)
    let posY:CGFloat = self.frame.height - (self.frame.height - rect.frame.height)

    rect.position = CGPointMake(posX,posY)
    rect.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    rect.lineWidth = 1

    self.addChild(rect)
```

The issue is that even though i believe all the maths is correct the rectangle is about 38 points/pixels that are under the screen, as you can see from the image below (the white border shows the limit).

For your information here is an output of the positions, heights and widths.

```
PosX: 100.5
PosY: 117.0
Rect Width: 201.0
Rect Height: 117.0
Frame Height: 768.0
Frame Weight: 1024.0
```

[image: Rectangle under the screen]

If i simple take this line but add 38 points/pixels it works, but why? Is there something I am missing?

```
    let posY:CGFloat = self.frame.height - (self.frame.height - rect.frame.height) + 38
```

[image: Rectangle in correct position]

Comment: check your scene's scalemode, it probably set to fill not fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer via the following two answers:

[SpriteKit coordinate system messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278692/spritekit-coordinate-system-messed-up)

[Problems understanding coordinate system SpriteKit using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163050/problems-understanding-coordinate-system-spritekit-using-swift/24170460#24170460)

The problem turns out to be with `GameScene.sks` having it's size set differently.

Open up `GameScene.sks` and go to 'Show SKNodeInspector' should be the third box in the top right hand side of the screen.

Then set the dimensions to 320 x 568

Save then run. Should be working.