# SpriteKit - Edge doesn't behave as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In order to define an rectangular edge, this is the code I wrote:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
/* Setup your scene here */

SKNode *edge = [SKNode node];

edge.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

[self addChild:edge];

}
```

I want this edge to wrap the whole screen, i.e bottom, top, left and right borders.

I wish that the objects that I add to my scene bounce on all borders. But, those objects only bounce on bottom and top part of the edge.

P.S: The same code, worked about a year ago when `SpriteKit` `GameScene.m`class had `-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size` instead of `-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently SpriteKit by default loads a scene from .sks file and by default, the scene size is set to 1024x768. That is probably why you are getting unexpected results (`self.frame` has different size in compare to a view).

There are few things you should keep in mind these days:

- When scene is loaded from .sks file, `initWithSize`: is never called. initWithCoder: is called instead. If you want to use `initWithSize`: you should create a scene in "old" way - using [sceneWithSize:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKScene/sceneWithSize:)
- In `initWithSize`: the view is always nil, so all the code which requires a view, should be moved to `didMoveToView`.
- In `viewDidLoad` a final size of a view may not be known yet. A proper implementation of `viewWillLayoutSubviews` can be used to get around this. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747945/3402095).

What I would suggest you, is to create a scene inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews` using `sceneWithSize`: method and initialize it with `view.bounds.size`. After that, you can create borders like this:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

Hint: It can be useful to enable visual physics representation. You can do this from view controller:

```
skView.showsPhysics = YES;
```

If all this doesn't help, check if your view has correct size. View can be wrongly sized if wrong launch images are supplied.

Hope this helps and make sense.